# Convergence of the series $\sum_k \frac{\frac{1}{k^2}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-\sqrt{a_k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose the series $\sum_k a_k$ is convergent, $a_k\geq 0$, $a_k\neq\frac{1}{k}$ for all $k$. Then is the following series convergent?
$$\sum_k \frac{\frac{1}{k^2}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-\sqrt{a_k}}$$

Comment: Hint: you can make the $k$'th term large by making $a_k$ very close (but not equal) to $1/k$.  Do that for infinitely many $k$...

Comment: Thank you, but then how can I guarantee that $\sum_k a_k$ is convergent? @RobertIsrael

Comment: It only has to be close to $1/k$ infinitely often. So try to find a subsequence of ${1/k}$ so that the sum converges. Also, it's easier to make $\sqrt{a_k}$ close to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ with an error term and then square.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, could you please see if my latest answer was correct?

Comment: Let $a_k  := \left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt k }} - \frac{1}{{k^2 }}} \right)^2  < \frac{1}{k}$ if $k=n^2$ with some $n\in \mathbb N$, and $a_k:=0$ otherwise. Can you show that this is a counter-example?